# Matplotlib how to draw on figure on PIL image

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

I've got a new problem here, I wish to inputs a PIL image object, and then draw the figure that generated from matplotlib, and then return the PIL image object. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you create the image in matplotlib, save it and then import it into pil?

```
xdata = pylab.arange(1961, 2031, 1)
pylab.figure(num=None, figsize=(20.48, 10.24), dpi=100, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
pylab.plot(xdata, ydata, linewidth=3.0)
pylab.xlabel(xlabel)
pylab.ylabel(ylabel)
pylab.title(title)
pylab.grid(True)

ram = cStringIO.StringIO()
pylab.savefig(ram, format='png')

import Image
im = Image.open(ram.read())
```

Comment: the OP probably wants to overlay the graph on an existing image which is not addressed.  I would either use the `pylab.savefig` with the `transparent` flag turned on and then combine the images in PIL, or I would describe how to use pylab's `imread`

Comment: Doesn't work for me, I get the following error: ```/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.pyc in open(fp, mode)
   2286     if isPath(fp):
   2287         filename = fp
-> 2288         fp = builtins.open(fp, "rb")
   2289     else:
   2290         filename = ""

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''
```